# Series read on Amazon where a girl's guild is doing a raid against a new boss, and after blacking out the guild leader wakes up as her golem character

Tags: story-identification, books, isekai

I'm looking for this series I read on Amazon where this girl's guild is doing a raid with minimal players against a new boss that was released in the game. As they're heading up to the game, everyone playing suddenly blacks out and when the guild leader wakes up, she finds she's her golem character and starts to think its a dream, until a horde of skeletons slaughter two people near her.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this a book series? Also, in roughly which year/s did you read it?

Comment: https://www.novelupdates.com/stag/golems/

Comment: It was a book series and i believe i read it around 2021

Answer (score 1):

This is Forever Fantasy Online, by Rachel Aaron. [Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D8QTWJM)

Tina is the guild leader, and plays the tank: A Stonekin Knight named Roxxy.

> The blackout couldn’t have lasted more than a few seconds. Tina almost wished it had been longer, though, because the moment she regained consciousness, all of her senses started trying to kill her.

> She watched in horror as the skeleton’s blue-white flaming sword swept down, slicing the incapacitated player’s head off in a single strike.
>  ...
>  There was no dismemberment in Forever Fantasy Online. Getting hit with a sword caused a stagger animation and lost hit points. There wasn’t even blood. Certainly nothing like this.